# Cycle of life of a system.timers.timer and how to call a method to inject data every x time? c#

Tags: c#, timer

I'm new here and also new in this world. I started to learn c# 2 months ago so be pacient please.

For practising purpouses I'm doing some kind of mocked service where I inject batch of data and my code do things with that but I want to do that my data only be verified every x period of time, that's where I get lost. Maybe this is more simple that I assume but I went to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0
and it didn't help me. I know this is what I need because I need something like what it says on the documentation:

> For example, suppose that you have an online sales application that continuously posts sales orders to a database. The service that compiles the instructions for shipping operates on a batch of orders rather than processing each order individually. You could use a Timer to start the batch processing every 30 minutes.

But I don't find any place where I could see where that's implemented or how should be the life cycle of this. Maybe is that I'm thinking this in a more difficult way that what it is?

For this code I have a Console App where I "mocked" my service calling three times to process de databatch:

```
    public class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
         BatchWithTimerTest test = new();
         Inventory inventory = new()
         {
           //data to compare with my inData
         }
         DataBatch inData = new()
         {
            //input data
         }
         test.setup(inventory);
         test.init();
         test.ProcessData(inData);
    
         test.ProcessData(inData);
    
         test.ProcessData(inData);
       }

    }
```

and my BatchWithTimerTest class:

```
public class BatchWithTimerTest
{
   private Inventory _inventory;
   private System.Timers.Timer timer;
   ReaderWriterLockSlim innerLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

   public void setup(Inventory inventory)
   {
      _inventory = inventory;
   }

   public void init()
   {
      timer =new(30000);
      timer.Start();
      timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => TimerElapsed(sender, e);
   }

   public void ProcessData(DataBatch inData)
   {
      //process my input data
   }

   private void TimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
      innerLock.EnterWriteLock();
      try
      {
          // should process my input data every 30 secs but how?
      }
      finally
      {
         innerLock.ExitWriteLock();
      }
   }
}
```

I'm sure my problem is with the concepts about how this works but I've been looking for info all day and I couldn't see anything helpful (or maybe I just didn't know where to look).
In my mind what this should do is to configure on init my timer and every 30 secs run one processData method to receive new input data but probably this is wrong.

I don't know if this kind of question are allowed on SO but any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you read my question you'll see I refer to that documentation on it. That super simple sample doesn't help me because I understand what timer does if I just whant to generate things inside it but NO how to do that timer receive data inside it from outside :) If you are going to keep going this way I will not answer you more. If you want to attack people randomly go twitter.

Comment: and, regarding the requirement of *my data only be verified every x period of time*, **reactive extension** is the ready to use solution here [Buffer](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#TimeShiftedSequences)

Comment: 1. I don't thing it was necessary to clarificate that I have a solution with some projects where I do implement my examples of what I want to learn to have all my stuff together. I use "program" for see console and my code is separate (I don't know why I need to argue this with you) 2.Well, that's maybe because I'm new and trying to learn and mix things to see how them work. That's why I'm here asking but its good o know maybe thats a wrong approach. 3.I'll take a look but I think this can't help me with the timer thing

Comment: I'll try to update my code to make a ninimal reproducible example, I though it was already. Also Ill take a look at that extension. Thank you

Comment: In your ProcessData, you can remember the inData in some list (in reality a database). Then in that TimerElapsed, copy the list, clear the original and "send" that copy

Answer (score 0):

I'm demonstrating my suggest way of code in such question, and also with my solution.

First, define the **data source**, that returns a data sequence and prints produced time of each. a callback(in real project maybe some equivalent events) is needed here because you won't want spin loop fast to check a global value.

```cs
        static Random rand = new Random();
        static void DataSource(object o)
        {
            Action<int> callBack = (Action<int>)o;
            int data = 0;
            while (data++ < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"produced data {data} at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss:ff}");
                callBack(data);
                //random can be removed, to be more minimal,
                //but keeping random looks like more interesting
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(rand.Next(100, 1000)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DataSource stopped");
        }
```

Then define the **real time handler**, it's purpose is to test the data source, and  compare with other solutions.
You need run the data source
in another thread, because we often want our timers be on the main(UI) thread.

```
        static void RealTimeHandle(int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed {n} at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss:ff}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(DataSource).Start((Action<int>)RealTimeHandle);
            Console.WriteLine("End of Main");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

*output*

```sh
End of Main
produced data 1 at 50:09:50
Consumed 1 at 50:09:51
produced data 2 at 50:10:25
Consumed 2 at 50:10:26
produced data 3 at 50:10:39
Consumed 3 at 50:10:39
produced data 4 at 50:11:02
Consumed 4 at 50:11:03
produced data 5 at 50:11:60
Consumed 5 at 50:11:60
produced data 6 at 50:12:33
Consumed 6 at 50:12:33
produced data 7 at 50:12:98
Consumed 7 at 50:12:99
produced data 8 at 50:13:39
Consumed 8 at 50:13:39
produced data 9 at 50:14:20
Consumed 9 at 50:14:20
produced data 10 at 50:14:97
Consumed 10 at 50:14:97
DataSource stopped
```

Last, the **buffered handler**.

```cs
        static Queue<int> buffer = new Queue<int>();
        static System.Timers.Timer timer;
        static void BufferHandle(int n)
        {
            buffer.Enqueue(n);
        }

        static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int cnt = buffer.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumed {buffer.Dequeue()} at {DateTime.Now:mm:ss:ff}");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(DataSource).Start((Action<int>)BufferHandle);
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);//consume data every 3 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
            //need consider stop timer somewhere
            Console.WriteLine("End of Main");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

*output*

```sh
End of Main
produced data 1 at 51:10:00
produced data 2 at 51:10:67
produced data 3 at 51:11:63
produced data 4 at 51:11:75
produced data 5 at 51:12:23
produced data 6 at 51:12:87
Consumed 1 at 51:13:01
Consumed 2 at 51:13:01
Consumed 3 at 51:13:01
Consumed 4 at 51:13:02
Consumed 5 at 51:13:02
Consumed 6 at 51:13:02
produced data 7 at 51:13:44
produced data 8 at 51:14:15
produced data 9 at 51:14:47
produced data 10 at 51:14:98
DataSource stopped
Consumed 7 at 51:16:01
Consumed 8 at 51:16:01
Consumed 9 at 51:16:01
Consumed 10 at 51:16:01
```

Note:

1. This code is just demonstrating the *minimal, reproducible* concept, not mean good design patterns.
2. I don't consider the race conditions between threads, since the time spans are long enough. and I don't see your related requirements.
3. If you still don't understand the *Cycle of life of a timer* , or have better ways for buffer hanlder, please comment and I'll try to update.